# Error creating bean when I run spring boot application

Tags: java

```
error:Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.gagner</groupId>
    <artifactId>gagner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gagner</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hello, Do you remember how you solved the error ?

Answer (score 22):

If you are under spring boot, jackson is added by default,

So the version you are adding manualy is probably conflicting with the one spring boot adds,

Try to delete the jackson dependencies from your pom

Comment: This works for me after removing jackson and restarting IDEA.

Comment: Worked for me aswell... thankss!!

Comment: Worked for me but default version  which I am getting in fat jar has vulnerability issues, kindly suggest

Comment: Hi ezzou, this works for me in one project, but in another project, `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotations are used and not found, what will be the alternate of this?

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to write this to a different answer, since the stacktrace you provided lead me to a completely different path.

I see in your *pom.xml* that you use `jackson-core:2.1.3` and `jackson-databind:2.1.3` version, which is more than 7 years old at this point.

However, based in [this list](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.3.RELEASE), the spring version you use expects the much newer `2.9.8` version. So probably, the method not found exception is because during runtime, spring gets a completely different version of the `ObjectMapper` class ([source code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/093254b2b35395f2afd797dd956a4a08fcc3ba06/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java)), which probably doesn't have the required `addMixIn()` method.

To fix this, since the parent of you *pom.xml* is set to the `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you can just delete the tag which sets the version of all of your dependencies starting with `jackson` and `spring`.

I quickly went through the original version of you *pom.xml* and cleaned it up a little, try replacing the content of your *pom.xml* with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.gagner</groupId>
    <artifactId>gagner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gagner</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In my case, removing the explicit jackson version did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this part of your **pom.xml**:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This was not meant to be in `project.dependencies`. It was mean to be in `project.dependencyManagement.dependencies`.

What is probably happening is that maven includes all the dependencies into your project on compile-time, but doesn't package them with your application.

In the meantime, you use a dependency that is available because of the part I highlighted, but the class is not available during runtime.

Please try to place the part I highlighted like this:

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>import</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    ...
</project>
```

Also pay attention to the scope, which changed from *provided* to **import**.

Comment: thanks for responding,am i supposed to include all my dependencies under project.dependencyManagement.dependencies  or only the dependency u mentioned inside the project.dependencyMangement.dependencies

Comment: only the one I mentioned. That is, because that artifact is not a dependency itself per say. Rather, it defines properties for other dependencies, like version and scope, so you don't have to, when declaring those dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for responding,Am I supposed to remove the parent pom when I use the spring boot dependency management because when I replace the dependency.Springboot dependencies with dependencymanagement.dependencies.dependency.springbootdependencies its not getting resolved

Comment: this is expected. I did overlook the fact that you have the spring-boot-parent as the parent of your project. In this case, you don't need the `spring-boot-dependencies` at all. What classes are missing if you remove it?

Comment: I did remove the spring-boot-dependencies from the pom.xml,and when i run the spring boot app again,the same set of errors are repeating,nothing changed even after i remove spring-boot-dependencies

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Comment: this is all expected so far. The part I'm interested in is what's after `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:`. As in what method is missing, from which class? Could you copy the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: Now we are trying to find out what is the dependency that you added before with the `spring-boot-dependencies` that you don't add now and add it manually.

Comment: Thanks for responding,I have posted the copy of my whole stacktrace below the 2 answers in the above,please have a look at that